# Java Spring resttemplate character encoding for query param

Tags: java, encryption, character-encoding, resttemplate

I am using Java Spring Resttemplate to get json via get request. Query parameter values can contain Russian characters. In such cases, I do not receive data from the API.

My code:

```java
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
        .path("/resume")
        .queryParam("text", "Java-разработчик")
        .build()
        .toUri();

log.info("URI: " + uri);
```

logs:

```
https://api.link.com/resume?text=Java-%D0%A1%D0%82%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A0%C2%B7%D0%A1%D0%82%D0%A0%C2%B0%D0%A0%C2%B1%D0%A0%D1%95%D0%A1%E2%80%9A%D0%A1%E2%80%A1%D0%A0%D1%91%D0%A0%D1%94
```

I also tried this, but it didn't help:

```java
1) 
restTemplate.getMessageConverters()
        .add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
2) 
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
        .path("/resume")
        .queryParam("text", URLEncoder.encode("Java-разработчик", HTTP.UTF-8))
        .build()
        .toUri();
```

[image]

What can be done so that Russian characters do not change and the request is sent directly with them?

That is, in the end, the request should look like this:

```
https://api.link.com/resume?text=Java-разработчик
```

Comment: Maybe this answers your question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295302/how-to-encode-cyrillic-symbols-in-http-requests-in-java

Comment: @JavaMan on the Internet, this method is also mentioned in many places, but unfortunately, this did not help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the encoding. Installing UTF-8 was helped only by using `encode(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` for `UriComponentsBuilder`

```java
URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
        .path("/resume")
        .queryParam("text", "Java-разработчик")
        .encode(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .build()
        .toUri();
```

Why `queryParam("text", URLEncoder.encode(myString, HTTP.UTF-8))` did not work remains a big mystery.